# Настройка переменных в fail2ban

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, fail2ban

Есть задача настроить *actionban* в *fail2ban* так, чтобы при выполнении блокировки на указанный в *actionban* адрес отправлялся запрос с данными в json-формате. В запросе на сервер приходят различные параметры, некоторые из которых actionban должен отправить в своём curl-запросе. Для этого в конфиг-файл добавил:

```
actionban   = curl -s -o /dev/null -X POST --data-urlencode "payload={\"ip\":\"<ip>\",\"device_id\":\"<device_id>\",\"uuid\":\"<uuid>\"}"  http://.....
```

И всё бы ничего, но, ни как не могу понять, где устанавливаются переменные для того, чтобы в мой запрос передались **device_id** и **uuid**.
Может кто настраивал подобно счастье?

Answer (score 0):

Есть два варианта.

Первый.
Здесь можно посмотреть список переменных, в которых содержится информация о запросе: [https://github.com/fail2ban](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/ca4da9d1d3f792562500182711abc149b2c741a1/fail2ban/server/actions.py#L376-L398) Собственно их должно хватить для поставленной задачи.

Второй.
При наступлении событий выполять bash (php, python) скрипт, где можно выполнить необходимое действие. Вот ссылка на статью: [webcp.io](https://webcp.io/custom-fail2ban-action/)